Authorize in API returning 401 error (invalid token) when using duende identityserver and docker compose
So I'm playing around with docker, .net (8) and angular.
I'm currently trying to secure my API by sending a token I obtained from my duende identityserver solution to the API to get data there.
However, every time I send a token (I tried through login in angular and sending token there and I tried through postman  by using the m2m.client client in a client credentials flow) I receive a 401 error "invalid token"
My Config file in Identityserver looks like this
    public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };


        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
           new ApiScope[]
           {
                new ApiScope("scope1"),
                new ApiScope("scope2"),
           };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
                new Client[]
                {
                    // m2m client credentials flow client
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "m2m.client",
                        ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                        ClientSecrets = { new Secret("511536EF-F270-4058-80CA-1C89C192F69A".Sha256()) },

                        AllowedScopes = { "scope1" }
                    },
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "frontend",
                        ClientName = "Angular frontend",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                        //RequireClientSecret = false,
                        ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                        AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                        RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html", "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4200/" },
                        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200/index.html" },
                        AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:4200" },

                        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            "openid",
                            "profile",
                            "scope1"
                        },
                    }
                };
    }

In my API I've added this in the Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("token")
                .AddJwtBearer("token", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5200";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
                });

and my  docker-compose looks like this:
version: '3.4'

services:
  identityserver:
    image: identityserver
    container_name: identityserver
    build:
      context: ./TestProject.Service.Core
      dockerfile: ./IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5200:8080"
      - "5201:8081"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

  core.database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: core.database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=core
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./.containers/core-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 3376:5432

  test.api:
    image: testapi
    container_name: test.api
    build:
      context: ./TestApi
      dockerfile: ./Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5040:8080"
      - "5041:8081"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

  frontend:
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: ./Limber.Frontend/limber.frontend
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:80


I ran similar projects without docker and then the client credentials flow works just fine. (I used the exact same config there)
Whenever I run it in docker I receive some kind of 401 invalid token error.
Depending on the settings I've added in the API, I receive errors like

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'http://localhost:5200' is invalid"

When I set validateIssuer to false I get

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

I've been looking at this for 2 days but I don't seem to get any further.

Hi @John I am having similar problem. Were you able to fix it?

Unfortunately not

If you get "The signature key was not found", then that means that the kid claim found in the access token is not found on the /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks endpoint.
I would:

Verify that the /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks is actually reachable from within the API service
Is the kid found in the access token found in the JWKS document?
Verify what the iss claim in the access token is and why it is not the same as the API Expects?

I also blogged about this at: Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core and here IdentityServer in Docker Containers.
